# Why am I getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError while running application in JBoss7.1.EAP

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

I am getting this error while running application in JBoss7.1.EAP and Spring5.0.0.RELEASE with Hibernate5.2.17.Final..The code is compiling fine..but when I am running the application it is failing .The code where its failing is :

```
public List loadTransformedObjectWithNativeSQL(String paramString, Map paramMap, Object[] paramArrayOfObject, Class paramClass)
  {
    Object localObject = null;
    NativeQuery localNativeQuery = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createNativeQuery(paramString);
    Iterator localIterator = paramMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (localIterator.hasNext())
    {
      Map.Entry localEntry = (Map.Entry)localIterator.next();
      String str = (String)localEntry.getKey();
      Type localType = (Type)localEntry.getValue();
      localNativeQuery.addScalar(str, localType);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= paramArrayOfObject.length; i++) {
        localNativeQuery.setParameter(i, paramArrayOfObject[(i - 1)]);
      }
    localNativeQuery.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(paramClass));
    return localNativeQuery.list();
  }
```

I also tried to block the hibernate jars of Jboss which doesnot support the Nativequery in the Jboss-deployment-descriptor.xml..but of no use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
        </exclusions>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="org.hibernate" />
            <subsystem name="org.hibernate.validator" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.hibernate" />
            <module name="org.hibernate.validator" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

The error is  given below, please check.

```
14:04:59,308 INFO  [com.gee.gecs.cosmos.dao.ServiceDaoImpl] (default task-3) ***************select cud.user_id validUser from cost_user cud where sso_id = ? and cud.rec_status_ind = '1'
    14:04:59,308 INFO  [com.gee.gecs.cosmos.dao.ServiceDaoImpl] (default task-3) ###############{validUser=org.hibernate.type.StringType@68d657ce}
    14:04:59,342 ERROR [com.gee.gecs.cosmos.aspect.ICAMExceptionHandler] (default task-3) A NestedServletException has occured in the application: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.createNativeQuery(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/hibernate/query/NativeQuery;
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:326)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:812)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.createNativeQuery(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/hibernate/query/NativeQuery;
        at com.gee.gecs.cosmos.dao.BaseDao.loadTransformedObjectWithNativeSQL(BaseDao.java:211)
        at com.gee.gecs.cosmos.dao.ServiceDaoImpl.getUserValidation(ServiceDaoImpl.java:450)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

The exception stacktrace is given above.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by placing the hibernate5.2.17Final jar in the or.hiberante.main folder replacing the old jars and changing the ref in module.xml